# MIN IF Function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a code in VBA which does the same function as those:

```
{=MIN(IF(rng1=criteria1,IF(rng2=criteria2,values)))}
```

and

```
{=MAX(IF(rng1=criteria1,IF(rng2=criteria2,values)))}
```

I have a lot of those function calls in document and it works really slow so I want to replace that...

Basically the result is to find a criteria in row and then in other range find minimum(higher than 0) and maximum value.

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the 'values' in the same row as both 'rng1' and 'rng2'?

Comment: yes, same row but different columns

Answer (score 1):

```
Sheets("Name").Range("A1").FormulaArray = "=MIN(IF(sheet1!C:C=""A"",sheet!E:E))"
```

where column C is the range with the criterion and column E contains the values where you would like to extract the min.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
How can I evaluate this formula lately?

Comment: run the code in vba, you would need to write more script. However, if you get to this point in vba it will work